# AWS Invalid Signature already attempted several resource examples

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I have built the following request string for amazon product lookup. I've looked up several resources and determined everything needed for computing the request signature.

Here is the string that computes the hash signature:

```
$str="
GET\n
webservices.amazon.com\n
/onca/xml\n
AWSAccessKeyId=accesskey&AssociateTag=all&SearchIndex=All&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2020-01-08T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2013-08-01";
$secret='secret';
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256',$str,$secret);
$sig=urlencode($sig);
```

Here is the final url compiled using the sha256 hashed string

```
$url="http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&SearchIndex=All&IdType=UPC&ItemId=635753490879&AWSAccessKeyId=accesskey&AssociateTag=all&Timestamp=2020-01-08T00%3A00%3A00Z&Signature=$sig";
```

And here is the api result:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Like ive said ive done some research and not sure whats wrong here

My IAM Group Permissions are:

`AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess`

and

`AdministratorAccess`

**UPDATE**

It stated i need to possibly convert to binary, so i added this function call to `$str`. I think this is where the error lies because i get the example functional without the binary conversion:

```
function strigToBinary($string)
{
    $characters = str_split($string);

    $binary = [];
    foreach ($characters as $character) {
        $data = unpack('H*', $character);
        $binary[] = base_convert($data[1], 16, 2);
    }

    return implode(' ', $binary);
}

 $str = strigToBinary($str)
```

Comment: Just a wild guess here. Do you think the `\n` are in conflict with your information ? maybe try to generate your string in a [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), whitout any `\n`?

Comment: @Nicolas nope did not resolve the issue